# Не могу получить имя модели из ошибки

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У меня есть rescue_form для отлова ошибок. Суть заключается в том, что deleted_model_message хранит в себе неймспейс %(model), имя модели может быть topic или subtopic. Получить имя модели планировалось с ошибки ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound. Ниже прикладываю свои попытки решения.

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
    redirect_to root_path, notice: t(:deleted_model_message, :model=> activerecord.errors.models)
  end

activerecord:
    models:
      topic: "Topic"
      subtopic: "Subtopic"
  deleted_model_message: "This %{model} no longer exists"
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Просто передайте полученную ошибку в виде аргумента в блок `rescue_from`, и всё получится.

```
rescue_from 'ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound' do |exception|
  redirect_to root_path, notice: t(:deleted_model_message, model: exception.model)
end
```